# How can I change focus from edit text on button click?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus, buttonclick

I want to know how can focus from `Edit_text` on `Button_click`.

[image]

Default `focus` on `Edit_text_1` when I click the `Save_Button_1` I want to remove `focus` from `Edit_text_1` and set `focus` on `Edit_text_2` and when I click the `Save_button_2` I want to remove `focus` from `Edit_text_2` and set `focus` on `Edit_text_1`.

**Edit**

Here is my Code-

**MainActivty.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et1,et2;
    TextView tv1,tv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);

        tv1.setText("edit");
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et1.clearFocus();
                et2.setFocusable(true);

//                String str = et1.getText().toString();
//                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//                msg.show();
            }
        });
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et2.clearFocus();
                et1.setFocusable(true);

//                String str = et2.getText().toString();
//                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
//                msg.show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <EditText
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/et1"
           android:layout_weight="0.1"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
           android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et2"/>
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/tv1"
           android:text="Save"
           android:textSize="20sp"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et2"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/et1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help me out.Thanks in the advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
 YOUR_EDITEXT_NAME.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get using this line of code as per your requirements

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

and for clear focus

```
 editText.clearFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
property in your xml file. For example (for edittext1):

  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext2"
```

Comment: It working only from edtitext2 to edittext1 but its not working on edittext1 to edittext2, and in xml I try  android:nextFocusDown="@+id/edittext2" for edittext1 and android:nextFocusUp="@+id/edittext1" for edittext2